# Eigen read and write LLT factorization to file

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

Let's say I have a matrix `MatrixXd A` and its LLT factorization:

```
LLT<MatrixXd> llt(A);
```

How can I save the factorization result to a file and load it later, so that we don't need to do the factorization again in the future runs?

I know we can obtain the `L` matrix via `MatrixXd L = llt.matrixL()` and save `L` to file, but I don't see a way to reconstruct the `llt` object from the `L` matrix.

Comment: Eigen doesn't provide serialization mechanisms, so the answer is probably there is no such routine.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Thanks! I guess I will have to store and load the `L` matrix, and manually solve the system using `L.triangularView<Lower>().solve()`

Comment: If you just want to solve linear systems, you can indeed write two triangular solves (making sure the order is correct, of course. For re-constructing an LLT object from a triangular matrix, there is an [open feature request](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/bz/show_bug.cgi?id=1599) which currently mostly needs an API-decision -- the implementation would be trivial.  And as @MatthieuBrucher said, Eigen provides no serialization, so that part still needs to be done by yourself.